# Advice on writing a rebuttal for a conference

Tags: publications, conference

I submitted a paper to a scientific conference through easychair website and I have just received the reviewers' comments with an opportunity for rebuttal, where they said:

"Please include in the revised version one page where you explain how you addressed the reviewers comments".

I have a few questions:

1. I understand that I have to submit a revised version of the 15-pages paper, but how can I include one extra page, I mean should I just add an extra page (page #16) at the end of the revised version or add it as the first page? or indlude it as a separate single page file?
2. I assume that the reviewers will look at the revised paper again after the deadline of the rebuttal phase, which means they are able to see all the comments (and my answers) from ~all~ the reviewers which will be summarized on that one page, is that correct?
3. One of the reviewers was confused with a definition at the beginning of the paper and he said that this definition is "so wrong" that he didn't even look at the rest of the paper (no complaint from the other reviewers about this definition).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you can submit two files, do that. If you are only able to submit one file, put the rebuttal on the first page and make the revised paper start from the second page.
2. Probably, yes. Within the one page you can make one section for each of the reviewers.
3. Make the definition clearer and explain what you have done in the rebuttal. If this reviewer gave any more detail, make sure you deal with his/her points.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with a conference submission is that there is a firm deadline, unlike a journal submission. The rebuttal is a *separate* document, seen by the program committee and reviewers that helps them make a speedy second review.

I'd guess that you should mention the definition issue if you can do it within the space requirement. The chair will eventually make a decision and may favor one opinion about the definition over another. The evaluation "score" at that point doesn't mean so much.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I can't seem to find an option on EasyChair to upload a separate document within the same submission. Is that mean I have to create a separate one-page pdf file for the rebuttal and then merge it with the revised version of the paper in one PDF file and submit the single file? 
I think what they saying "include in the revised version one page" is a little confusing.

Comment: The chair of the program committee is probably pretty visible. Ask them.

Comment: I had previously asked them but they did not answer. For some reason, they seem not willing to answer the authors at this time. I am thinking to combine the rebuttal page (as the first page) and the revised paper into one file (just like combining the cover letter and the resume into one document for a job submission), although I am not sure if this is what they are asking.